# Is there way to copy journey via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder

I've wondered if there is a way to copy journey via API.
I already asked to Salesforce Support and Support told me there isn't API for this.
but I've wondered if there is an unofficial API.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use the "Copy Journey" from the UI, it can be a faster way. Basically, copying a journey through API will need to retrieve that journey information (GET journey) then you use these information to create the copy journey (POST journey). FYI, "Copy Journey" feature is actually doing the same steps. So if you still want to do it through API route you can refer to @zuzannamj 's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why they would tell you that, because it is possible and it’s widely used and officially documented.

[Get journey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_interaction/getInteractionById.html):

**GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{id}**

Retrieves a single journey by ID or key. To call this resource, assign your API Integration the Automation | Interactions | Read scope.

[Create journey](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_interaction/postCreateInteraction.html):

**POST /interaction/v1/interactions
Overview**

Creates or saves a journey. To create a new journey provide the request body in the appropriate Journey Specification. Please read the Journey Spec page to understand which properties are required to create a journey via the API. The id, key, createdDate, modifiedDate, status and definitionId are assigned by Journey Builder and are never to be passed in as parameters for creating a journey. To call this resource, assign your API Integration the Automation | Interactions | Read scope.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. I'll try based on you said!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to create a journey with EntrySource and Email Activity set. I guess triggers and activities JSON parameter has to do with this but There's no sample code at all. Is there any sample code I can refer to?

Comment: I don’t have any sample code but you can try googling it, there’s plenty SFMC developer resources out there. And to get all parameters, do what @DucLe suggested - send a GET request and you will more or less get the JSON that you need for the POST request

Comment: okay! thanks for your help :)